# How to achieve butter smooth motion in pixi.js (without any lags / spikes)

Tags: 2d-games, pixi.js, game-loop

I'm trying to achieve butter smooth motion using pixi.js. It should be a simple thing I suppose but it seems I can't obtain it.

Sometimes I get spikes / micro lags. I've tested it on my Ubuntu 20.04 dev machine using the latest Chrome version and the latest PIXI js (5.3.3 actually). Same thing happens on the latest Chrome on my old Macbook pro (late 2013)

This is the code I'm using:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  view: document.querySelector("#view"),
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  backgroundColor: 0x0,
  antialias: false
})
const ticker = PIXI.Ticker.system
const box = new PIXI.Graphics()
box.lineStyle(1, 0xff0000)
        .drawRect(
                100, 
                100, 
                100, 
                100)
app.stage.addChild(box)

let speed = 4
app.ticker.add( (dt) => {
  if (box.x < 0) {
    speed *= -1
    box.x += speed * dt
  }
  if (box.x > 800) {
    speed *= -1 
    box.x += speed * dt
  }
  box.x += speed * dt
})
```

Here a running version https://codepen.io/ferama/pen/LYZVBMx

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to eliminate occasional stuttering in a WebGL animation.  Underneath every web rendering framework (including PixiJS) is a call to requestRenderFrame().  Which, as its name implies, is a *request* to the browser to repaint the window.  You will not always get back a "sure, do it right now!" from the browser.  Sometimes the browser is busy.  Sometimes, your javascript garbage collector has to run.  Sometimes a butterfly flaps its wings in China...

Point is, the only way to completely control your framerate is to use a technology such as DirectX that allows complete control over the actual rendering and display hardware (mostly!).  WebGL is simply not geared for that.

Comment: Thanks. Weird enough I built the same minimal example using Monogame on linux. The microlags are less frequent but is happening there too. In the meantime I had the opportunity to test the pixi version on windows and seems a lot more stable there where the micro lags are very rare.

Comment: Question: what you see in console when you start page with pixi.js application on linux? `"PixiJS 5.1.3 - WebGL 2...` ? Do you see then `WebGL 2` part? Also, you should upgrade your pixi version to newest one (is 5.3.3 now) : https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases

Comment: The console is showing PixiJS 5.3.3 - ✰ WebGL 2 ✰  (there was  a typo in my original question that I edited thanks)

Answer (score 0):

It was running just fine for me, however you can try setting antialias: true and resolution: window.devicePixelRatio.

Comment: tested but without success unfortunately